# cabal - missing or bad header file primitive-memops.h

Tags: haskell, cabal

I was getting the error message

```
missing or bad header file primitive-memops.h
```

I encountered this problem when installing http://www.haskellcraft.com/craft3e/Start.html (Simon Thompson's Haskell Craft book source code). Frustrated me for several hours. There were lots of hits on this question in google but nothing that was an answer.

I had checked the files & used the -v3 flag & tried specifying the --extra-include-files directives.

My linux environment is an Amazon EC2 instance based on an Amazon linux AMI. My haskell environment is: ghc 7.6.3 (obtained as distribution from justhub, not git)

Comment: Please separate your question from your answer. We keep them separate on Stack Overflow. Also, highlighting "Solved" is not necessary - you'll find most of the questions on the Haskell tag are solved, so uncluding the word in the title is redundant and misleading, as it wrongly suggests that other questions are not solved.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is not crystal clear for this issue. I eventually figured it out by trying to compile the primitive-memops.c file & found I did not have a c compiler installed.

I did already have ghc 7.6.3 installed & running.

So the problem was that there was no c compiler installed on my Amazon Linux server, so I did:

```
sudo yum install gcc
cabal install
```

This completed successfully.

(Moved from self-answer text in question)